# How can I get the top 3 strings with the highest value in this program?

Tags: python

I have a python program where I print strings like

```
@SP_YSNSB id=0
0054 log out
@SP_23RTY id=0
0387 pop
@TRIO_9078 id=0
0098 hench
@TRE_4657838.c id=0
0056 pop
@WRYE_LKP.CO id=0
0078 ffg
```

The "@SP_23RTY" is the header and "0387 pop" is the number of lines executed before it looped out.

How can I print the top 3 headers with the top 3 highest values of lines?

The output should be

```
@SP_23RTY id=0
0387 pop
@TRIO_9078 id=0
0098 hench
@WRYE_LKP.CO id=0
0078 ffg
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please format the text in your question and put what have you tried. Thanks

Comment: " I have a python program..." Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re`:

```
import re
lines = list(filter(None, content.split('\n')))
grouped = [[lines[i], lines[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(lines), 2)]
new_grouped = sorted(grouped, key=lambda x:int(re.findall('\d+', x[-1])[0]), reverse=True)[:3]
for a, b in new_grouped:
  print(f'{a}\n{b}')
```

Output:

```
@SP_23RTY id=0
0387 pop
@TRIO_9078 id=0
0098 hench
@WRYE_LKP.CO id=0
0078 ffg
```